# UTF-8 not working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, utf-8

I have an Issue with the UTF-8 Charset. 
When I define UTF-8 as the used charset on my Webpage, all my special characters transform into �.
I tried the following methods and everything gave me the same result.

via PHP

```
 header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

via HTML

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

via .htaccess

```
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

---

EDIT:
All my Databases in MySQL (where my Text-Content lies) are defined as utf8_general_ci

---

+EDIT:
Solved
The Issue lied in PDO.
After adding following code it worked.

```
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Comment: If the data is coming from a database then this too must be set for utf-8. Also, what font are you using - this may not have the particular characters that you need to display.

Comment: Did you make sure that your text file is saved as utf-8 ? in notepad++ or something

Answer (score 0):

Most fonts don't include all UNICODE characters, are you sure the font you use on your website can render character you are displaying?

You can download [Noto](http://www.google.com/get/noto/#/) in any form and shape to test if that is your issue.

Comment: It's one of the Standard HTML Fonts Times New Roman. And without the definition it get's showed correctly on Windows. I wanted to define UTF-8 because Mac don't show it up correctly.

Comment: Could you post the characters you're trying to display?

Comment: The Standard characters like äüö

Comment: Is the data coming from a database? If so is the db set correctly to UTF-8 also?

Comment: Yes my SQL Database is set to UTF-8